# while fetch_array() not printing all rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to print img paths from db in a while to print them all, but it's only printing the first one.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("  SELECT *
                                FROM user_uploads
                                WHERE userID = ?
                                LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

        if (!empty($row['description'])) {
            $desc = $row['description'];
        } else {
            $desc = 'Descripción de la imagen';
        }

        echo '
                <div id="form-main">
                    <form class="form" action="" method="post" name="image">
                        <img src="/images/user_uploads/' . $row['image_path'] . '" alt="' . $row['image_name'] . '" height="600" width="600">
                        <p class="text">
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input image" id="image" placeholder="' . $row['image_name'] . '"/>
                        </p>
                        <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" value="Cambiar nombre" id="button-blue"/>
                            <div class="ease"></div>
                        </div><br><br><br><br>
                    </form>
                    <form class="form" action="" method="post" name="image">
                        <p class="text">
                            <textarea name="text" type="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input comment" id="comment" placeholder="' . $desc . '"></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" value="Cambiar descripción" id="button-blue"/>
                            <div class="ease"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>';
    }
}
```

In my testing, I have 4 image paths saved in the table. I don't see what's wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the limit from your query

Comment: `LIMIT 9999999999` ;) or just remove the `LIMIT 1` altogether.

Comment: Oh! I see, I just copied from another script and I forgot to remove that. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `LIMIT` clause in your query that basically limits your result set to just 1 record. Remove it to retrieve **all** records.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `limit` from your query, You are limiting your result there.

and than your `if` statement should look like this.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("  SELECT *
                                FROM user_uploads
                                WHERE userID = ?
                                ")) {
```